# Connected components recursive function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, recursion

I'm new to MATLAB and I'm trying to implement connected components algorithm. Here is code:

```
% Binary image (BI)    
% Labelled image (LI)
LI = zeros(r,c);

n = 1;
    for i = 2:r-1
        for j = 2:c-1
            if BI(i,j) && LI(i,j) == 0
                label(i, j, n, BI, LI)
                n = n + 1;
            end
        end
    end
```

and my label function:

```
function label(x, y, n, BI, LI)

LI(x,y) = n;

    for i = x-1:x+1
        for j = y-1:y+1
            try
                if BI(i,j) && LI(i,j) == 0
                    label(i, j, n, BI, LI)
                end
            catch
                continue
            end
        end
    end

    end
```

This works for hours and nothing happens. I can't fix the recursive part! It's probably because of my poor programming level. A little help would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use some built-in functions such as `bwconncomp` ?https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html

Comment: Thanks but i'm trying to implement this function :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that MATLAB does not pass function arguments by reference. When you modify `LI` inside the `label` function, it does not change the global `LI` that you created as your label image.

To update your label image you have to get a return value from your function:

```
function LI = label(x, y, n, BI, LI)

LI(x,y) = n;

    for i = x-1:x+1
        for j = y-1:y+1
            try
                if BI(i,j) && (LI(i,j) == 0)
                    LI = label(i, j, n, BI, LI);   % update LI
                end
            catch
                continue
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Now that `label` returns the updated label image, you need to set `LI` each time you call `label`, as in the commented line above, and in the calling script:

```
% Binary image (BI)    
% Labelled image (LI)
LI = zeros(r,c);

n = 1;
    for i = 2:r-1
        for j = 2:c-1
            if BI(i,j) && (LI(i,j) == 0)
                LI = label(i, j, n, BI, LI);   % update LI
                n = n + 1;
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a point that I've missed. But unfortunately my problem remains same.

Comment: @Burak Interesting. I tried this on a sample image I generated and it worked, but maybe there's something I missed. Do you have some input for which this fails?

Comment: I just found that I missed BI(i,j) and LI(i,j) both must equal to 0 ! Thank you again.

Comment: So you're labeling the image where `BI == 0`? That would be the opposite of what I assumed.

Comment: My mistake :) I'm labelling the image if it's black. So, yes it must be like BI == 0 .